How to get the value from MDTextField inside a MDialog() in py file (kivymd2.0.1)
I want to get the value of text in the MDTextField. In .kv you just use the id as a reference like this:
id : my_text

but, in the MDialog() inside the py file you use = instead of : and a lot of values you just pass them as "" or between ().
But with id, i dont know what to do.
Look, this is the example:
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '375')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '650')
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.uix.button import MDButton, MDButtonText
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import (
    MDTextField,
    MDTextFieldHintText,
)
from kivymd.uix.dialog import (
    MDDialog,
    MDDialogButtonContainer,
    MDDialogContentContainer,
)

class MyBL1(BoxLayout):
    dialog = None
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def challenge_friend(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                MDDialogContentContainer(
                   MDTextField(
                        MDTextFieldHintText(
                            text= "Usuario",
                        ),
                    #id='tipo', #?????
                    mode= "outlined",
                   ),  
                pos_hint= {'center_x': 0.5},      
                orientation="vertical",
                spacing = "10dp",
                ),   
            MDDialogButtonContainer(
                Widget(),
                MDButton(
                    MDButtonText(text="Cancel"),
                    style="text",
                    #on_release = self.stop_challenge,
                ),
                MDButton(
                    MDButtonText(text="Aceptar"),
                    style="text",
                    #on_release = self.create_challenge()
                ),
            size_hint_x = 1,         
            spacing="10dp",
        ),
        )
        self.dialog.open()
    
    def create_challenge(self, *args):
        usuario = self.ids.tipo.text  #???
        print(usuario)   #?????
        self.dialog.dismiss()
        self.dialog = None

KV = """
<MyBL1>
    Button:
        font_size: "30sp"
        text: "Create Dialog"
        on_release: root.challenge_friend()
"""
Builder.load_string(KV)

class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.screenm = ScreenManager()
        self.mybl_uno = MyBL1()
        screen = Screen(name="first screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.mybl_uno)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)
        return self.screenm


MyApp().run()

As you see, I tried putting the id reference as '' but, that does not work. By the way just
id=tipo, doesn't work
How I can acomplish this in this scenario?
Thanks!

Another approach is to use the kv language and ids. Here is a modified version of your code that uses this approach:
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '375')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '650')
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.dialog import (
    MDDialog
)

# My extension of MDDialog
class MyDialog(MDDialog):
    mybl1 = ObjectProperty(None)


class MyBL1(BoxLayout):
    dialog = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def challenge_friend(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MyDialog(mybl1=self)  # create MyDialog instead of MDDialog
        self.dialog.open()

    def create_challenge(self, *args):
        usuario = self.dialog.ids.tipo.text
        print(usuario)
        self.dialog.dismiss()
        self.dialog = None


KV = """
<MyBL1>
    Button:
        font_size: "30sp"
        text: "Create Dialog"
        on_release: root.challenge_friend()
        
<MyDialog>:
    MDDialogContentContainer:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "10dp"
        MDTextField:
            id: tipo
            mode: "outlined"
            MDTextFieldHintText:
                text: "Usuario"
    MDDialogButtonContainer:
        size_hint_x: 1
        spacing: "10dp"
        Widget:
        MDButton:
            on_release: root.mybl1.stop_challenge()
            MDButtonText:
                text: "Cancel"
                style: "text"
        MDButton:
            on_release: root.mybl1.create_challenge()
            MDButtonText:
                text: "Aceptar"
                style: "text"
            
"""
Builder.load_string(KV)


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.screenm = ScreenManager()
        self.mybl_uno = MyBL1()
        screen = Screen(name="first screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.mybl_uno)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)
        return self.screenm


MyApp().run()


Thank you very much!!!!!!!! i did not know how to create the MDialog in the kv file. I think i would use this approach!

An easy way to do what you want is to save a reference to the MDTextField. Try changing your challenge_friend() method to:
def challenge_friend(self):
    if not self.dialog:
        # create the MDTextField and save a reference to it
        self.text_field = MDTextField(
                    MDTextFieldHintText(
                        text="Usuario",
                    ),
                    mode="outlined"
        )

        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            MDDialogContentContainer(
                self.text_field,  # use the MDTextField created above
                pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5},
                orientation="vertical",
                spacing="10dp",
            ),
            MDDialogButtonContainer(
                Widget(),
                MDButton(
                    MDButtonText(text="Cancel"),
                    style="text",
                    # on_release = self.stop_challenge,
                ),
                MDButton(
                    MDButtonText(text="Aceptar"),
                    style="text",
                    on_release = self.create_challenge
                ),
                size_hint_x=1,
                spacing="10dp",
            ),
        )
    self.dialog.open()

Then your create_challenge() method can be:
def create_challenge(self, button):
    usuario = self.text_field.text  # ???
    print(usuario)  # ?????
    self.dialog.dismiss()
    self.dialog = None
    self.text_field = None

The ids dictionary is only created when you use the kv language. You could create your own dictionary of ids if you have several that you need to keep track of. However, the kv created ids are weak references, so they will not prevent the widgets in the dictionary from being garbage collected.
